# How can I retrieve the contents of a Zope filesystem?

Tags: python, plone, zope

I ran a Website on Zope/Plone for several years, until the server crashed catastrophically. I have no interest in bringing up the Web site again (nor am I convinced that I even could, since the version of both Zope and Plone that it was based on has been obsolete for at least six years), but I'd love to be able to get the content out so that I can use it. It's stored in a Zope filesystem (i.e. Plone-2.5.3/zeocluster/server/var/Data.fs). Is there any set of tools out there that would allow my to write a Python script to save the content to files? Or is there another way to get at the content short of attempting to reinstall the whole Web site? Data.fs is over half a gigabyte, so there's a fair bit in there.

I'm running Python 2.7 and 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bite the bullet and re-install Plone 2.5.3. While you can theoretically read the ZODB, its contents consist of Python pickles which won't make sense without the classes that were pickled.

Re-installing 2.5.3 will have some challenges, but if you start with the "Unified Installer" for 2.5.3 (https://plone.org/products/plone/releases/2.5.3), you'll at least have all the source pieces, including the matching Python.

Once you've got 2.5.3 running again, you'll have the code base you need to read and export the data via Python script.

Comment: +1 ... and if you are not wanting to reinvent the wheel I'd make the data export script to be: [collective.jsonify](https://github.com/collective/collective.jsonify)

Answer (score 0):

Zope/Plone uses [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/) for storage. Try that on a copy of `Data.fs`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Following up on that, I'm trying zodbbrowser. Almost all of the entries start with "broken product" so i'm not able to actually look at the content yet. Still working on it.

Comment: Since your version of plone is quite old, you might try the actual version of ZODB that's in your Plone. Failing that, try installing the old version of Plone and export your data.